# Presenting modal over modal add a gap between navigation bar and view content

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

Seems like New iOS 13 modal presentation has issue when presenting a modal over a modal. A gap will be appear between navigation bar and content. check the screenshot.

[image: Gap]

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing UI fix the issue:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
          navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
     }
}
```

[image: gap fixed]